# No View Model registered for View 'Core:Page:GeneralPage'

Tags: dxa

I am using DXA 2.0 CTP 2. It's a fresh, installation, and I'm running the .NET version of the application as a source build using the DxaFramework solution. In the Unity config, `ContextClaimsProvider` is mapped to `AdfContextClaimsProvider`, and of course, my `Web.config` points to my own discovery endpoint, but for the rest, it's "out of the box", including `<add key="default-module" value="Core"/>` in the `Web.Config`.

When I try to run the application, I get an error message:

> ERROR No View Model registered for View 'Core:Page:GeneralPage'. Check that you have registered this View in the 'Core' area registration.

I'm trying to load the home page, so I've checked the Home Page Template: the Page View Name there is `GeneralPage`. This looks correct to me, and given that the default module is Core, my expectation would be that the framework should be looking for a `Core:GeneralPage` view, rather than `Core:Page:GeneralPage`.

What is this error message trying to tell me? Do I need to modify or expand my conceptual understanding of DXA in some way? How should I change my setup to get this working?

Comment: Did you add the Core module from https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/tree/master/webapp-net/Core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View names are scoped to a specific Area and specific Controller. The fully qualified View name `Core:Page:GeneralPage` means a View called `GeneralPage` for Controller `Page(Controller)` in Area `Core`.

If all is well, this file should exist in your Web App: `Areas\Core\Views\Page\GeneralPage.cshtml`. Note that this is not the case by default if you build from sources, because the Core Module is not part of the solution, but in a separate repository (`dxa-modules`).

If you build the Core module from sources too and you have the `DXA_SITE_DIR` environment variable set to the location of your Web App, the required artifacts (Views + DLL) will be copied to your Web App.

Comment: Great - thanks Rick - just the insight I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Core:Page:GeneralPage is how missing views are reported.

Many solutions do NOT include "Core" by default.

Appstore Community link
https://appstore.sdl.com/web-content-management/app/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-net/608/